# Trouble with using For variables within for loop Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am having trouble with a bit of code, I don't really know how to describe it
but I can explain what doesn't work

```
FOR /D /r "%cd%\files\" %%G in ("*") DO (
  echo In folder: %%~nxG
  set /a count=1
  echo %%~fG

  For /R "%%~fG" %%B in ("*.mp3") do (
      call :subroutine "%%~nB"
  ) & echo. >>%archive%.txt

)
```

just if you want to know what the subroutine does:

```
:subroutine
 echo %count%:%1>>%archive%.txt
 echo %count%: %1
 set /a count+=1
 GOTO :eof
```

I figured out that it doesn't read the `%%~fG` inside the second for loop.
Can someone please help me.

I am using `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need another subroutine as for options are parsed before outer for tokens. Check the following example:

```
@echo off

echo :::ATTEMPT 1:::
for %%a in (z) do (
    rem the expected delimiter is z and result should be ++::%%a
    for /f "delims=%%a tokens=1,2" %%A in  ("++z%%%%az--") do echo %%A::%%B
)


echo :::ATTEMPT 2:::
for %%a in (z) do (
    call :subr "%%~a"
)

exit /b

:subr
rem the expected delimiter is z and result should be ++::%%a
for /f "delims=%~1 tokens=1,2" %%A in  ("++z%%%%az--") do echo %%A::%%B
```

the output is:

> :::ATTEMPT 1:::
>
> ++z::zz--
>
> :::ATTEMPT 2:::
>
> ++::%%a

As you can see in the first attempt the `%%a` symbols are taken as delimiters. But subroutine arguments are parsed imminently so they can be used.
To make your code work you can try with:

```
FOR /D /r "%cd%\files\" %%G in ("*") DO (
  echo In folder: %%~nxG
  set /a count=1
  echo %%~fG

 call ::innerFor "%%~fG"

)
...
exit /b %errorlevel%
:innerFor
  For /R "%~1" %%B in ("*.mp3") do (
      call :subroutine "%%~nB"
  ) & echo. >>%archive%.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For /R "%%~fG" %%B in ("*.mp3") do (
```

Sadly, `for/r` can't be run with a variable as the dirname.

I'd suggest

```
call :anothersubroutine "%%~fG"
```

and
    :anothersubroutine
    For /R "%~1" %%B in ("*.mp3") do (

- but I've not tried it. Perhaps you'd need to `set` %%~fG into a variable and use `%var%` (not tried that either...)